# Loss of accuracy with large values

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I am having a problem with large values.
Please help me.

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            double rate=1.0000;
            double value=scanner.nextDouble();
            value*=rate;
                BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(value);
            System.out.println(bigDecimal);
```

But when I enter the input as

```
121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212
```

My output is

```
121212121212121209445819616146456785067331026944
```

Please help me.
How can I get values accurately?

Comment: **Shameless plug:** Go to http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/, type in the number you entered (121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212), and click "Double".  This will explain why you are getting the output you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in using `BigDecimal` if you are initializing it with a `double`, which has a limited precision.

You should initialize it with a String instead :

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
String value=scanner.nextLine();
BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(value);
System.out.println(bigDecimal);
```

If you wish to multiple your input by a value other than 1 (multiplying by 1 is pointless), use `bigDecimal.multiply(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I want to do the multiplication also. Even if I change the value from string to double same value is displayed. How to do the multiplication?

Comment: @abdulrahuman For example : `BigDecimal product = bigDecimal.multiply(new BigDecimal("3526347634625623537"));`

Comment: @abdulrahuman You can't represent the number `121212121212121212121212121212121212121212121212` as a double without loss of precision. That's the motivation to use `BigDecimal` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I just mentioned one for multiplication so that the difference in output would be clear. Thank you so much it worked